# Problems with GCD dispatching to main thread in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have this piece of code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //accessing the internet
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [myObject myFunction];
    });
});
```

and in myFunction:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("anotherQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //long task that takes seconds
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //this is never executed
        NSLog(@"Got to main thread.");
        //updating the UI
    });
});
```

Can someone explain why the block ^{ NSLog(@"Got to main thread."); }); doesn't get executed?

Comment: Hmm, I get a headache just looking at this. Move the NSLog to replace the [myObject myFunction]. That should accomplish what you are trying to do. Why would you call the main queue inside an async queue inside the main queue inside the async queue. Head hurts again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main queue / main thread is blocked.

Put an `NSLog()` after the `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())...` in `myFunction`.   I'd bet it doesn't get printed because that block is never executed (as you indicate).

If that is true, set a breakpoint on that `dispatch_sync`, then look at the stack trace of the main queue/thread.   That should give you a clue as to why it is blocked.

Answer (score -3):

You're creating two queues with identical names. It doesn't matter that your variables for those queues are in different contexts, a queue is a global construct in your application. Name each of the queues differently [using the reverse-DNS style](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_create).

Comment: Neither true, nor does it explain the behavior.   The queue's name is nothing but a cosmetic aid to help debugging.

Comment: @bbum - I know you worked on obj-c, but can you point out the relevant documentation? The Apple doc I linked to does say it helps in debugging, but nowhere does it indicate that two queues created with the same name would not refer to the same underlying object.

Comment: It doesn't say that they do, either…

Comment: @RyanR That'd be one of those behaviors that would be explicitly documented and would be backed by API like `dispatch_get_queue_name()`.  It'd also be slow, thus requiring a really good reason to make it so, and it would be alien to the threading API that it is replacing (which, again, would require justification for going there).   As well, though it would be an implementation detail, it is easy to test for.  But, sure, the docs could be clarified;  feel free to file an enhancement bug!

Comment: Can confirm that queues are not uniqued by name. I use many serial queues of the same name in my code, and have verified the count of OS_dispatch_queue objects in my process using heap(1).